# String doesn't work at all

Tags: java, android, string

I have really no idea why it doesn't show text.

If you look at the class 2, then then I save nimi2 as shared preference. But it doesn't show up in class 1. I made small test. I replaces name 2 with "plaplapla" (note the "") and it showed up as plaplapla. But I want it to show up whatever person types as his name. I am new to java. I am yet again really out of ideas :(. Can someone help?

```
package viimane.voimalus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainStuff extends Activity {
    TextView tere;
    String nimi;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        tere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTere);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean nimiOlemas = preferences.getBoolean("nimionolemas", false);
        nimi = preferences.getString("nimi2", "");
        if (nimiOlemas == false){
             startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, nimekysija.class), 0);
             finish();
        }
        if (nimiOlemas == true){
            tere.setText("Tere " + nimi);
        }

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // get data from shared preference here
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

---

```
package viimane.voimalus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class nimekysija extends Activity {

    EditText nimi;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    String nimi2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nimekysija);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        nimi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNimekysija);
        nimi2 = nimi.getText().toString();
        Button kysOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNimekysija);
        kysOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("nimi2", nimi2); // nime kirjutamine
                editor.putBoolean("nimionolemas", true); // nimi on kirjutatud!
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.MAINSTUFF"));
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

---

```
and XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:text="" android:id="@+id/tvTere" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:text="Palun sisestage oma nimi!" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/etNimekysija" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </EditText>
    <Button android:text="OK!" android:id="@+id/bNimekysija" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="onAddClick"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my answer. I removed onActivityResult and in 2nd class just made small move. Moved `nimi2 = nimi.getText().toString();` into button onClick :).

Thank you ntc for help :). I couldn't wait for your respond so I just searched googled a lot and so on :P.

Answer (score 1):

Instaed of using startActivity(), use method called `startActivityForResult()`. and in class 1 override another method called `onActivityResult()`, in that method you try to get String. Right now you are trying get values from `sharedPreference` before its stored inti it in class2.

//edited

```
package viimane.voimalus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainStuff extends Activity {
    TextView tere;
    String nimi;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        tere = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTere);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean nimiOlemas = preferences.getBoolean("nimionolemas", false);
        if (nimiOlemas == false){
             startActivity(new Intent("viimane.voimalus.NIMEKYSIJA"));
             finish();
        }
        if (nimiOlemas == true){
            nimi = preferences.getString("nimi2", "");
            System.out.print("töötab!");

            tere.setText("Tere " + nimi);
        }
        System.out.print("töötab2!");
    }
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // get data from shared preference here
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

edit: I accidently edited it. Fix'd now

Comment: With what method I replace onActivityResult() exactly?

Comment: you need not replace.. just like onCreate() method there is another method in Activity called onActivityResult() you need to override it... look at my edited answer as well..

Comment: hmm, now it doesn't even show anything at all :/...... I think I wrote something wrong... Shall I "answer question" with current code what I have?

Comment: ooh, it gives respond "Hello null" not name tho, but it is small progress :)!!! Aww, my brain is messed up :P

Comment: Updated opening post with current code I have. Really weird one it is :/... I really have no idea how the heck am i supposed to put all those things.

Comment: post all your code.. let me help you out.. you need to work on object oriented languages a bit.....:(

Comment: By all you mean XML included? And yes, I need that help :).